# Reviewer stats rejected count changing drastically in short period of time

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I checked the stats of a user who rejected two edits last night. The first time I checked his stats, it said he had approved approximately 2000 edits and rejects about 12000. I looked at his stats a few minutes later on another rejection and it showed only 20 rejections. It now shows 20 rejections on both edits as seen below. I'm inclined to believe the larger number is true as he rejected reasonable edits that were approved by the rest of the users. Is this a bug or how might this occur?

[image]

Comment: Yes, a bug, and was reported already.

Comment: Thanks, nicael. I promise I searched quite a bit before posting the question. Sorry if this is a duplicate.